# Direct formula for summing XOR

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have to XOR numbers from 1 to N, does there exist a direct formula for it ?

For example if  `N = 6` then `1^2^3^4^5^6 = 7` I want to do it without using any loop so I need an O(1) formula (if any)

Comment: I think you'd have to consider each bit in turn so it'd be O(log N) at the very least. Why do you need an O(1) solution?

Comment: Please explain you approach a bit more.

Comment: @Rup: note that any arithmetic operations are, fundamentally, `O(log n)` in the sense that if you're working with bigints and not fixed-size words, they take `O(log n)` time. However, even with bigints, this formula gives an `O(1)` solution for the xor sum (assuming you can overwrite the input to use as the output, or optionally return a constant 0/1 as output).

Comment: Actually I was slightly wrong. I was thinking it was `N+1` in the "plus means xor" sense, rather than truly `N+1`. The latter can never be `O(1)`. Oh well...

Comment: @R. sure - my expectation at the time of the comment (before there were any answers or formula) was that this couldn't be computed in a single expression and you'd need a separate computation to determine each bit in the answer individually, i.e. more explicitly log_2 N. But, more through observation of patterns than maths, we've ended up with a formula after all.

Answer (score 36):

Your formula is `N & (N % 2 ? 0 : ~0) | ( ((N & 2)>>1) ^ (N & 1) )`:

```
int main()
{
    int S = 0;
    for (int N = 0; N < 50; ++N) {
        S = (S^N);
        int check = N & (N % 2 ? 0 : ~0) | ( ((N & 2)>>1) ^ (N & 1) );
        std::cout << "N = " << N << ": "  << S << ", " << check << std::endl;
        if (check != S) throw;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
N = 0: 0, 0             N = 1: 1, 1             N = 2: 3, 3
N = 3: 0, 0             N = 4: 4, 4             N = 5: 1, 1
N = 6: 7, 7             N = 7: 0, 0             N = 8: 8, 8
N = 9: 1, 1             N = 10: 11, 11          N = 11: 0, 0
N = 12: 12, 12          N = 13: 1, 1            N = 14: 15, 15
N = 15: 0, 0            N = 16: 16, 16          N = 17: 1, 1
N = 18: 19, 19          N = 19: 0, 0            N = 20: 20, 20
N = 21: 1, 1            N = 22: 23, 23          N = 23: 0, 0
N = 24: 24, 24          N = 25: 1, 1            N = 26: 27, 27
N = 27: 0, 0            N = 28: 28, 28          N = 29: 1, 1
N = 30: 31, 31          N = 31: 0, 0            N = 32: 32, 32
N = 33: 1, 1            N = 34: 35, 35          N = 35: 0, 0
N = 36: 36, 36          N = 37: 1, 1            N = 38: 39, 39
N = 39: 0, 0            N = 40: 40, 40          N = 41: 1, 1
N = 42: 43, 43          N = 43: 0, 0            N = 44: 44, 44
N = 45: 1, 1            N = 46: 47, 47          N = 47: 0, 0
N = 48: 48, 48          N = 49: 1, 1            N = 50: 51, 51
```

**Explanation:**

1. Low bit is XOR between low bit and next bit.
2. For each bit except low bit the following holds:

   - if N is odd then that bit is 0.
   - if N is even then that bit is equal to corresponded bit of N.

Thus for the case of odd N the result is always 0 or 1.

Comment: `(N % 2 ? 0 : ~0)` can be expressed as `((N&1) - 1UL)`, as long as you're using `unsigned` integers so wrap-around from `0` to `-1UL` is well defined, i.e. all bits set, like `~0UL`.  This may help compilers optimize, especially because `N&1` is already needed in another part of the expression.

Comment: Looks like `(N & ((N&1)-1UL)) | ( ((N & 2)>>1) ^ (N & 1) )` compiles nicely for x86 with recent gcc/clang.   See asm output on the Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/g/bsfMsS.  (I put 3 versions of it into inline functions with a couple tmp vars to make them more readable.)

Comment: Including code from some other answers: https://godbolt.org/g/PJHFwS (and AArch64 output as well as x86-64)

Answer (score 14):

**edit**
**GSerg** Has posted a formula without loops, but deleted it for some reason (undeleted now). The formula is perfectly valid (apart from a little mistake). Here's the C++-like version.

```
if n % 2 == 1 {
    result = (n % 4 == 1) ? 1 : 0;
} else {
    result = (n % 4 == 0) ? n : n + 1;
}
```

One can prove it by induction, checking all reminders of division by `4`. Although, no idea how you can come up with it without generating output and seeing regularity.

*Please explain your approach a bit more.*
Since each bit is independent in xor operation, you can calculate them separately.
Also, if you look at k-th bit of number `0..n`, it'll form a pattern. E.g., numbers from 0 to 7 in binary form.

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

You see that for k-th bit (k starts from 0), there're `2^k` zeroes, `2^k` ones, then `2^k` zeroes again, etc.
Therefore, you can for each bit calculate how many ones there are without actually going through all numbers from 1 to n.

E.g., for `k = 2`, there're repeated blocks of `2^2 == 4` zeroes and ones. Then,

```
int ones = (n / 8) * 4; // full blocks
if (n % 8 >= 4) { // consider incomplete blocks in the end
    ones += n % 8 - 3;
}
```

Comment: GSerg deleted it because it was wrong (off by 1 every time). I actually deleted it multiple times, fixing something each time :)

Comment: I posted the question prior to login so I can't officially accept it now but I could I believe your answer is the best one :)

Comment: Neat and straightforward

Answer (score 10):

For odd `N`, the result is either `1` or `0` (cyclic, 0 for `N=3`, 1 for `N=5`, 0 for `N=7` etc.)

For even `N`, the result is either `N` or `N+1` (cyclic, N+1 for `N=2`, N for `N=4`, N+1 for `N=6`, N for `N=8` etc).

Pseudocode:

```
if (N mod 2) = 0
  if (N mod 4) = 0 then r = N else r = N+1
else
  if (N mod 4) = 1 then r = 1 else r = 0
```

Comment: Yes, it turns to be right. Curious what is the math background behind that. :)

Comment: Shouldn't be `(N mod 4) = 1` on the second line?

Comment: +1 good work! That will teach me to generate sample of the sequence before 'solving' it :)

Comment: @usta: No, I'm checking for `(N mod 2) = 0` if the first place (opposite to the [C++ version by Nikita Rybak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932346/dirrect-formula-for-summing-xor/3932461#3932461)

Comment: You originally had `if (N mod 4) = 3 then r = 1 else r = 0` which is what I have commented on.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say the function that XORs all the values from 1 to N be XOR(N), then

```
XOR(1) = 000 1 = 0 1 ( The 0 is the dec of bin 000)
XOR(2) = 001 1 = 1 1
XOR(3) = 000 0 = 0 0
XOR(4) = 010 0 = 2 0
XOR(5) = 000 1 = 0 1 
XOR(6) = 011 1 = 3 1
XOR(7) = 000 0 = 0 0
XOR(8) = 100 0 = 4 0
XOR(9) = 000 1 = 0 1
XOR(10)= 101 1 = 5 1
XOR(11)= 000 0 = 0 0
XOR(12)= 110 0 = 6 0
```

I hope you can see the pattern. It should be similar for other numbers too.

Comment: Neat: i.e. for N odd `XOR(N) = (N & 1) ^ ((N & 2) >> 1)` and for N even `XOR(N) = N ^ ((N & 2) >> 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

the LSB gets toggled each time the N is odd, so we can say that

```
 rez & 1 == (N & 1) ^ ((N >> 1) & 1)
```

The same pattern can be observed for the rest of the bits.
Each time the bits `B` and `B+1` (starting from LSB) in `N` will be different, bit `B` in the result should be set.

So, the final result will be (including N): `rez = N ^ (N >> 1)`

EDIT: sorry, it was wrong. the correct answer:

for  odd N: `rez = (N ^ (N >> 1)) & 1`

for even N: `rez = (N & ~1) | ((N ^ (N >> 1)) & 1)`

Comment: What rez stands for ? if final answer then it's not correct I think :)

Comment: `1^2^3==0`, but `3^(3>>1)==2`

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by Alexey Malistov! A variation of his formula: `n & 1 ? (n & 2) >> 1 ^ 1 : n | (n & 2) >> 1` or equivalently `n & 1 ? !(n & 2) : n | (n & 2) >> 1`.

Answer (score 2):

this method avoids using conditionals `F(N)=(N&((N&1)-1))|((N&1)^((N&3)>>1)`

```
F(N)= (N&(b0-1)) | (b0^b1)
```

If you look at the XOR of the first few numbers you get:

```
N     |  F(N)
------+------
0001  |  0001
0010  |  0011
0011  |  0000
0100  |  0100
0101  |  0001
0110  |  0111
0111  |  0000
1000  |  1000
1001  |  0001
```

Hopefully you notice the pattern:

> if `N mod 4 = 1` than `F(N)=1`
>   if `N mod 4 = 3` than `F(N)=0`
>   if `N mod 4 = 0` than `F(N)=N`
>   if `N mod 4 = 2` than `F(N)=N` but with the first  bit as `1` so `N|1`

the tricky part is getting this in one statement without conditionals ill explain the logic I used to do this.

take the first 2 significant bits of N call them:

`b0` and `b1` and these are obtained with:

```
b0 = N&1
b1 = N&3>>1
```

Notice that if `b0 == 1` we have to `0` all of the bits, but if it isn't all of the bits except for the first bit stay the same. We can do this behavior by:

`N & (b0-1)`  : this works because of 2's complement, `-1` is equal to a number with all bits set to `1` and `1-1=0` so when `b0=1` this results in `F(N)=0`.. so that is the first part of the function:

```
F(N)= (N&(b0-1))...
```

now this will work for for `N mod 4 == 3` and `0`, for the other 2 cases lets look solely at `b1`, `b0` and `F(N)0`:

```
b0|b1|F(N)0
--+--+-----
 1| 1|    0
 0| 0|    0
 1| 0|    1
 0| 1|    1
```

Ok hopefully this truth table looks familiar! it is `b0 XOR b1 (b1^b0)`. so now that we know how to get the last bit let put that on our function:

```
F(N)=(N&(b0-1))|b0^b1
```

and there you go, a function without using conditionals. also this is useful if you want to compute the XOR from positive numbers a to b. you can do:
`F(a) XOR F(b)`.

Comment: You should provide an explanation why this works. SO is not about giving a copy-paste answer, but providing an explanation such that in the future, people can solve their own problems.

Comment: thanks CommuSoft I will explain anything I put on here from now on

Comment: wow thanks for adding that formatting! didn't even know you could do that. ha

Answer (score 1):

With minimum change to the original logic:

```
int xor = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    xor ^= i;
}
```

We can have:

```
int xor = 0;
for (int i = N - (N % 4); i <= N; i++) {
    xor ^= i;
}
```

It does have a loop but it would take a constant time to execute. The number of times we iterate through the for-loop would vary between 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
!(n&1)*n+(n%4&n%4<3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine without any issues for any n;

```
unsigned int xorn(unsigned int n)
{

    if (n % 4 == 0)
      return n;
   else if(n % 4 == 1)
       return 1;
   else if(n % 4 == 2)
       return n+1;
  else
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `unsigned n` so modulo is more efficient.  (As written, the compiler can't just use `n&3` because `-7 % 4` in C is `-3`, not +3.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, makes sense, updated it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. This will solve your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670524/4973570

To calculate the XOR sum from 1 to N:

```
int ans,mod=N%4;
if(mod==0) ans=N;
else if(mod==1) ans=1;
else if(mod==2) ans=N+1;
else if(mod==3) ans=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If still someone needs it here simple python solution:

```
def XorSum(L):
    res = 0        
    if (L-1)%4 == 0:
        res = L-1
    elif (L-1)%4 == 1:
        res = 1
    elif (L-1)%4 == 2:
        res = (L-1)^1
    else: #3
        res= 0
    return res
```