# Need a short, complicated C++ code and a longer, understandable version

Tags: c++

In [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/9272/2210) question, I tried to give an example of two ways of doing the same thing in C++: one short but complicated "fancy" piece of code; and a longer but more readable and understandable way of doing the same thing. The question asks whether it's better to have a well-commented fancy piece of code or a self-commented (i.e. no comments) longer version.

The problem with my example was that the fancy version turned out to be more understandable than the non-fancy version. Since I can't think of any good examples, I figure I'd try asking here. So what I need is two examples of C++ code which produce the exact same result, but in one version the code is short but very complicated and cannot be understood immediately without having to think about it, and a longer but much more readable and understandable version.

I want someone to look at the fancy version and go "Shit, that's complicated. I'm glad it's commented, otherwise I wouldn't have understood what it does" and then look at the longer version and go "Ah, I understand what it does, even without comments". The shorter example should be something like 1-10 lines and the longer maybe 10-30 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
//direct formula for xoring all numbers from 1 to N
int Sum = (N & (N % 2 ? 0 : ~0) | ( ((N & 2)>>1) ^ (N & 1) ) );
```

instead of:

```
int Sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
{
   Sum ^= i; //or Sum = Sum ^ i;
}
```

Formula taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932346/direct-formula-for-summing-xor)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Looks... very complicated. Thanks. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something along these lines?

First version:

```
int srtcpy(char *dst, char const *src) {
    char *dst_start = dst;
    while (*dst++ = *src++); // Incrementally copy *src to *dst until *src is 0
    return dst_start;
}
```

Second version:

```
int srtcpy(char *dst, char const *src) {
    char *dst_start = dst;
    while (*src != '\0') {
        *dst = *src;
        dst = dst + 1;
        src = src + 1;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    return dst_start;
}
```

The more interesting question now is: What about the compiled versions of these functions: do they differ once compiled and optimized? *Is the first actually faster than the second?* What is the actual gain of writing *fancy* pieces of code?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Unfortunately that's almost the exact example I provided. ^^ But apparently a lot of people thought that the "fancy" version was not all that fancy, and more readable and understandable than the "non-fancy" version. We're only interested in readability now, so how _fast_ it actually executes is of no importance. Well, it may be if you want to argue for using the fancy version over the non-fancy, but that's another story.

Comment: well, changing `foo++` to `foo = foo + 1` hardly makes C code more readable, expect perhaps for a person who sees C for the first time. For the rest of us, `foo++` is easier to understand (since it's a visual pattern the brain grasps without thinking too much, unlike `foo = foo + 1` which is uncommon in real C code)

Comment: I think your "problem" might be that `while (*dst++ = *src++);` is actually a well known pattern immediately recognized for what it is by many C programmers. The first time a "newbie" sees it, it might need picking apart to be understood fully.