# How to take the xor of the numbers from 1..n, for a given n? (eg 1^2^3^...^n)?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor, bitwise-xor

This is an interview problem I encountered, I know how to get the brute force solution by repeatedly XORing numbers, but I have no idea how to do this more efficiently.

I saw this solution on careercup:

```
typedef unsigned long long UINT64;

UINT64 getXOROne2N(UINT64 n) {
    switch (n % 4) {
        case 0: return n;
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: return n + 1;
        case 3: return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't exactly understand the logic here even with the guy's explanation, can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: what do you not understand in this?

Comment: proper explanation given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670379/find-xor-of-all-numbers-in-a-given-range).

Comment: The difficult part would seem the upper bits, with `n` showing up every other result giving a clue.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mathematical pattern that arises when you look at the answer for ascending values of `n`. It looks something like a rotation with four steps. This is because we are oscillating back and forth between xoring odd and even numbers into various combinations of previous even and odd results. Each successive xor brings us a quarter way through the rotation. I'll demonstrate and explain.

Let's examine this case by case, starting from the beginning, `n=1`:

```
00000001
```

Note that this falls within `case 1` in the solution, where the result returned is 1. Also note that this value of `n` is odd, so it necessarily ends in `1`.

Now, when we compute the solution for `n=2`, it will be the solution to the previous answer xored with the new value of `n`:

```
00000001
       ^
00000010
--------
00000011
```

Note that this falls within `case 2` of the solution, where the result returned is `n + 1`. Also note that in this case `n` is even, necessarily ending in `0` -- so when xored to the previous result of 1 (odd), we are only flipping additional bits on, and so the result in any similar case will likewise always be `n+1`

For the next value, naturally the result of `getXOROne2N(3)` is the previous result, xored by `3`. Interestingly, this wipes us out to zero:

```
00000011
       ^
00000011
--------
00000000
```

This makes sense when we think about it; the result to `getXOROne2N(2)` was `n+1 = 2+1 = 3`, so naturally enough when we xor into that the next value along (`n+1`) that will cancel all the signed bits back out to 0. Also note that this falls into `case 3` in the solution you presented.

Now, any time we compute the next `getXOROne2N` value after we have 0, it will just be the next value of `n` -- so `getXOROne2N(4)` is 4.

```
00000000
       ^
00000100
--------
00000100
```

Note that this falls neatly into `case 0` in the solution you presented.

Now, because the `4` xored to the previous result of 0 is even, the result necessarily has a trailing 0. Thus the next value in line to xor into the fold, 5, must have this previous bit configuration but with the last bit set to 1, meaning when we xor it to the previous result to compute `getXOROne2N(5)`, we'll cancel all but the last bit out and arrive back to 1:

```
00000100
       ^
00000101
--------
00000001
```

And thus we form our rotation. The next after this will xor an even number in and thus yield `n+1` (odd), and the next after that will cancel back out to `0` (xoring in an odd number to produce this even result), and then we'll get the next `n` (which must be even), and so then xoring in the subsequently odd next value up will cancel out all bits but the last which remains on, yielding 1 again.

It's a vicious cycle! But pretty neat, I think.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note is that any 4 numbers in a row starting from number divisible by 4 will result in 0 if XORed:

```
    ...00 - starting with any binary digits
    ...01
    ...10
    ...11
XOR -----
        0 : 4 times (...), twice 1 for both lower digits
```

It effectively means that only last numbers after max divisible by 4 before `n` do form actual result (you can group all numbers before in quads each giving 0).

So, it comes

```
%4    n               calc           result
0   ...00  ->  ...00 =               n
1   ...01  ->  ...00 XOR ...01 =     1
2   ...10  ->  ...10 XOR 1 = ...11 = n + 1
3   ...11  ->  ...11 XOR ...11 =     0
```