# Python fast XOR over range algorithm

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures

There is a programming challenge that requires one to generate an **XOR** checksum based on sequence start number and an interval length.

It requires you to iterate the sequence based on the interval length and at each iteration keep reducing the number of elements picked for the checksum calculation.

*Example:*

---

if the start number is **0** and the interval length is **3**, the process would look like this:

**0 1 2**/

**3 4** / 5

**6** / 7 8

where the  XOR (^) checksum is **0^1^2^3^4^6** == **2**

Likewise, if the start is **17** and the interval length **4**, the process would look like:

**17 18 19 20** /

**21 22 23** / 24

**25 26** / 27 28

**29** / 30 31 32

which produces the checksum **17^18^19^20^21^22^23^25^26^29** == **14**

*My solutions approach*

---

Using Recursion

```
import operator
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)

def answer(start, length):
    lst = [range(start+length*n, start+length*n+length) for n in xrange(length)]
    return my_reduce(lst, length)

def my_reduce(lst, length):
    if not lst: return 0
    l = lst.pop(0)
    return reduce(operator.xor, l[:length], 0) ^ my_reduce(lst, length-1)
```

Iterative approach using a generator

```
def answer(start, length):
    return reduce(operator.xor, gen_nums(start, length))


def gen_nums(start, length):
    l = length
    while l > 0:
        for x in xrange(start, start+l):
            yield x
        start = start + length
        l = l - 1
```

*Problem*

---

**My two approaches do not run fast enough.**

They do fine for trivial calculations e.g the ones in the examples but take significantly more time when the interval length is large e.g **1000**

### **Questions**

- What computer science concepts are being tested by this challenge?
- What is the right algorithmic approach?
- what are the right data structures to use?

I need to understand why my solution performs poorly and what algorithm and data structures fit this challenge.

Comment: Any solution evaluating term by term will do O(length²) operations. You do not need any data structure to speak of. Try to understand [dd2's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39941113/3789665). Try to repeat the process with the terms _that_ algorithm handles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am suggesting a simple optimization over your solution.

Use this method to get the xor of a range[a,b]

```
def f(a):
     res = [a, 1, a+1, 0]
     return res[a%4]

def getXor(a, b):
     return f(b) ^ f(a-1)
```

Now for a given interval you can compute XOR checksum in `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`.

```
def gen_nums(start, length):
    l = length
    ans = 0
    while l > 0:
        ans^= getXor(start,start+l-1)
        start = start + length
        l = l - 1
    return ans
```

**Explanation**

Let us denote *f(n)=1⊕2⊕3⊕⋯⊕n*, where *⊕* denotes XOR operation. The XOR of all numbers between *A* and *B* can be represented by *f(B)⊕f(A−1)*, because *x⊕x=0*

Now we can find out easily that,

[image]

Time Complexity - O(1)

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670379/find-xor-of-all-numbers-in-a-given-range)

[reference two](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/84803/how-to-find-xor-of-all-the-elements-in-given-range)

Comment: (Good enough for me if you put the reference before the 1st code block, and/or give it a more descriptive label.)

Comment: @ee2 Hey, this solution does not even work with the sample values given by the OP.

Comment: To fix `gen_nums`, put the `l = l - 1` _before_ `ans^= getXor(start,start+l)`

Comment: No worries. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40401834/4014959) for a corrected version of your code, as well as an optimised version.