# Speed up Python2 nested loops with XOR

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, nested-loops, xor

> [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39941113/5961780) of the question this is marked duplicate of is wrong and does not satisfy my needs.

My code aims to calculate a hash from a series of numbers.

It is easier to understand the structure in the form of a matrix. If I have 16 numbers starting from 29 the structure will be: (start=29, length=4)

29, 30, 31, 32,
33, 34, 35, 36,
37, 38, 39, 40,
41, 42, 43, 44

The given algorithm specifies the the hash will be the XOR of the numbers given in bold:

**29, 30, 31, 32,** //,
**33, 34, 35,** //, 36,
**37, 38,** //, 39, 40,
**41,** //, 42, 43, 44

Hash=`29^30^31^32^33^34^35^37^38^41`=`34`

---

My code is:

```
def answer(start, length):
    val=0
    c=0
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(length):
            if j < length-i:
                val^=start+c
            c+=1
    return val
```

The time required to compute for large values like `answer(2000000000,10**4)` is way too much.

---

Constraints:

- Py2.7.6
- Only standard libraries except for bz2, crypt, fcntl, mmap, pwd, pyexpat, select, signal, termios, thread, time, unicodedata, zipimport, zlib.
- Limited time to compute.

Currently computing the test parameters (unknown to me) give me a timeout error.

---

How can the speed of my code be improved for bigger values?

Comment: What are you trying to compute?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39941113/4014959 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670379/find-xor-of-all-numbers-in-a-given-range

Comment: @PM2Ring The first link is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.\

Comment: @khelwood See the mentioned link.

Comment: @sbrm1 When I ask a question like "What are you trying to compute?" I don't mean that I need to know that for my own peace of mind; I mean that your question is missing some information that it really ought to include.

Comment: @khelwood I didn't mean that.

Comment: Combined both answers and got this: http://rextester.com/CJBP16034 . Can't post it as question's marked as duplicate. Still putting it here for sharing.

Comment: @PM2Ring The answer of the question of which this question was marked as a duplicate of fails even with the sample values in that question, let alone my values.

Comment: @sbrm1 That's no good! Is the second question I linked helpful? I assume _that_ code works, since it's supposed to be competition-winning code, but I didn't choose it as the dupe target because it's not Python. But I'll re-open this question.

Comment: @PM2Ring The second question will not work directly, but I guess I may be able to implement some part of it in my code.

Comment: As khelwood mentioned earlier you need to mention in your question _exactly_ what you're trying to compute. Your failure to do that before was probably responsible for at least one of your downvotes, and now that the question is opened again there's a chance that you'll get more downvotes if you don't improve your question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Will edit it now.

Comment: @PM2Ring Edited the question

Comment: @sbrm1 I found the bug in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940954/python-fast-xor-over-range-algorithm and notified the author. See my answer below for details, as well as an optimised version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *is* a bug in the accepted answer to [Python fast XOR over range algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940954/python-fast-xor-over-range-algorithm): decrementing `l` needs to be done *before* the XOR calculation. Here's a repaired version, along with an `assert` test to verify that it gives the same result as the naive algorithm.

```
def f(a):
    return (a, 1, a + 1, 0)[a % 4]

def getXor(a, b):
    return f(b) ^ f(a-1)

def gen_nums(start, length):
    l = length
    ans = 0
    while l > 0:
        l = l - 1
        ans ^= getXor(start, start + l)
        start += length
    return ans

def answer(start, length):
    c = val = 0
    for i in xrange(length):
        for j in xrange(length - i):
            n = start + c + j
            #print '%d,' % n,
            val ^= n
        #print
        c += length
    return val

for start in xrange(50):
    for length in xrange(100):
        a = answer(start, length)
        b = gen_nums(start, length)
        assert a == b, (start, length, a, b)
```

Over those ranges of `start` and `length`, `gen_nums` is about 5 times faster than `answer`, but we can make it roughly twice as fast again (i.e., roughly 10 times as fast as `answer`) by eliminating those function calls:

```
def gen_nums(start, length):
    ans = 0
    for l in xrange(length - 1, -1, -1):
        b = start + l
        ans ^= (b, 1, b + 1, 0)[b % 4] ^ (start - 1, 1, start, 0)[start % 4]
        start += length
    return ans
```

---

As  Mirek Opoka mentions in the comments, `% 4` is equivalent to `& 3`, and it's faster because bitwise arithmetic is faster than performing integer division and throwing away the quotient. So we can replace the core step with

```
ans ^= (b, 1, b + 1, 0)[b & 3] ^ (start - 1, 1, start, 0)[start & 3]
```

Comment: Using `something % 4` could be replaced by `something & 3` which on my machine seems to be faster by about 10% (measured with timeit).

Comment: @MirekOpoka Of course! Why didn't I think of that? :) Thanks! I've edited my answer.

Comment: Typo: `(0, start - 1, 1, start, 0)` should be `(start - 1, 1, start, 0)`. Also note this answer doesn't handle an edge case properly. i.e.  the loop continues past the maximum because it always assumes a 'square'. But solution(1999999999, 2) should return `1999999999^2000000000`

Comment: @jiggunjer Thanks for spotting that typo! :oops: But I don't agree with your edge case. I think `solution(199, 2)` should return `199 ^ 200 ^ 201`, i.e., 2 numbers on the 1st row, 1 number on the 2nd row.

Comment: You dont have to agree. The original foo.bar problem explicitly said there is no ID 2000000001. So that worker cant be scanned as part of the checksum. Assuming it's existence is the bug.

Comment: @jiggunjer Oh, ok. I just answered the question as stated above. I don't know (or care) about a "foo.bar" problem on some other site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can replace the inner loop and if with:

`for j in range(length - i)
    val^=start+c
    c+=1
c+=i`

This should save some time when i gets bigger

I'm afraid I can't test this right now, sorry!

Comment: Faster, just not fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that, with the input you have in `answer(2000000000,10**4)` you'll never finish "in time".

You can get a pretty significant speed up by improving the inner loop, not updating the `c` variable every time and using `xrange` instead of `range`, like this:

```
def answer(start, length):
    val=0
    c=0
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(length):
            if j < length-i:
                val^=start+c
            c+=1
    return val


def answer_fast(start, length):
    val = 0
    c = 0
    for i in xrange(length):
        for j in xrange(length - i):
            if j < length - i:
                val ^= start + c + j
        c += length
    return val


# print answer(10, 20000)
print answer_fast(10, 20000)
```

The profiler shows that `answer_fast` is about twice as fast:

```
> python -m cProfile script.py
366359392
        20004 function calls in 46.696 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   46.696   46.696 script.py:1(<module>)
        1   44.357   44.357   46.696   46.696 script.py:1(answer)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    20001    2.339    0.000    2.339    0.000 {range}

> python -m cProfile script.py
366359392
        3 function calls in 26.274 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   26.274   26.274 script.py:1(<module>)
        1   26.274   26.274   26.274   26.274 script.py:12(answer_fast)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

But if you want major speed ups (orders of magnitute) you should consider rewriting your function in Cython.

Here is the "cythonized" version of it:

```
def answer(int start, int length):
    cdef int val = 0, c = 0, i, j
    for i in xrange(length):
        for j in xrange(length - i):
            if j < length - i:
                val ^= start + c + j
        c += length
    return val
```

With the same input parameters as above, it takes less than 200ms insted of 20+ seconds, which is a 100x speedup.

```
> ipython

In [1]: import pyximport; pyximport.install()
Out[1]: (None, <pyximport.pyximport.PyxImporter at 0x7f3fed983150>)

In [2]: import script2

In [3]: timeit script2.answer(10, 20000)
10 loops, best of 3: 188 ms per loop
```

With your input parameters, it takes 58ms:

```
In [5]: timeit script2.answer(2000000000,10**4)
10 loops, best of 3: 58.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Faster, but slower than @Tiemenjoustra 's answer

Comment: The Cython version above is basically C, without any Python overhead, so it's very close to a hand-written C version of it.

Comment: So the only difference is `cdef`? I'm not familiar with Cython.

Comment: Won't work for me as Cython is not built in to py2.7.6.

Comment: The `cdef` and the `int`s in the function parameters. I know Cython is not included in the stdlib. To be frank, your loop is so easy that a simple C function + `ctypes` bindings would be enough.

Comment: Great, will try it later sometime.