# Optimizing matrix operation to complexity less than O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, bit-manipulation, big-o, dynamic-programming

given a 2D square(n*n) matrix, I am trying to find if there is a way to perform an operation on the upper triangle of the matrix **in less than O(n^2) time[preferably in linear time]**. Please note that the matrix elements are consecutive as shown in the example.i.e : all values in each row and column are sorted.I have solved this using O(n^2) complexity. Example below :

`21 22 23 24 25
 26 27 28 29 30
 31 32 33 34 35
 36 37 38 39 40
 41 42 43 44 45`

Now, if I want to perform a XOR operation on the upper triangle, it would mean XOR -ing the below elements :
21^22^23^24^25^26^27^28^29^31^32^33^36^37^41 = 35, which is the desired result.

In other words, I am basically XOR-ing :

`21 22 23 24 25
 26 27 28 29
 31 32 33 
 36 37
 41`

I tried to solve using DP by finding a pattern by generating their binary equivalents, but could not find any consistent patterns.

Comment: This question is a bit vague. So assuming that all what you want is calculating the xor on the upper triangle. **Then O(n^2 / 2)=O(n^2) is the lower bound** as you need to look at each element in the triangle (=n^2/2 elements). This can change for *some calculations*, but the xor-function is highly sensitive (not much pruning possible; the last value to look at could change all bits).

Comment: @sascha On the other hand, if the matrix contains n*n elements, that would be regarded the size of the input -> O(n/2).

Comment: is there any pattern to generate the given numbers in the 2d matrix?

Comment: Which are the possible values in that matrix?

Comment: Thanks for your input. There was an edit in the question which I have incorporated now. The elements in the matrix are consecutive. i.e the rows and columns are sorted. I was trying to figure out if there is a way to use bit manipulation to generate the result without actually having to XOR every element in the matrix. This could potentially remove the need to traverse the elements in the matrix , thereby reducing the complexity[if possible].

Comment: When you say "consecutive", do you mean that the element `m[i+1] = m[i] + 1`?

Comment: @ Mark Ransom - Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Edit after the comment:

Using the method from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670379/find-xor-of-all-numbers-in-a-given-range)

```
long long f(long long a) {
     long long res[] = {a,1,a+1,0};
     return res[a%4];
}

long long getXor(long long a, long long b) {
     return f(b)^f(a-1);
}
```

create a loop like this:

```
long FinalXor = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i< n; i++){
    FinalXor =FinalXor^getXor(m(i,0),m(i,0)+ n-i)
}
```

You will only need to loop over the first value of each row generating an Algorithm with complexity of O(n)

Comment: Thanks for your response .I did something similar. However, I was wondering if there was a way to play around with bit manipulation that could give the answer directly without having to actually XOR all the consecutive numbers. There was an edit in the question. I forgot to mention that the elements in the matrix are consecutive as shown in the example. In other words, row and col elements are sorted. That edit is incorporated now anyways.

Comment: Well, with that in mind i think there is a better solution, use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670379/find-xor-of-all-numbers-in-a-given-range) solution to calculate the xor of the elements of each line and than xor all of the results.
Since the values are consecutives you can calculate it in O(N) applying the getXor method for each line at a time

Comment: There is a small modification in the fact that the range is `FinalXor =FinalXor^getXor(m(i,0),m(i,0)+ n-(i+1))`.  However, I could not clearly understand how they are forming the lookup table in the referenced post. It will be of great help if you could please explain how the pattern of {a,1,a+1,0} is determined.

Comment: @user5566364 As explained in the answer given in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670379/find-xor-of-all-numbers-in-a-given-range) mentioned, the xor operation will "loop" in every four terms: for element starting at **a** you will have `(a, 1, a+1,0)`, so you only need to know if the choosen term is the first, second, third or fourth `res[a%4]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can do this in O(n) time given the constraint on the pattern of the numbers in the grid.
You first need to write a function that will be able to give you the result of xor sum of all the numbers in [1,n] in O(1) time.

```
//iteratate in every row of the grid to find out xor sum of that row
//and xor add that sum with the final_xorsum
int final_xorsum=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    final_xorsum^=xor_sum(biggest_num_in_row_i)^xor_sum(smallest_num_in_row_i-1);
}
cout<<final_xorsum<<endl;

//this function will retrun xor sum value of all the numbers [1...n]
//example: xor_sum(5) = 1^2^3^4^5
int xor_sum(int n) {
    int vals[4] = {a,1,a+1,0};
    return vals[a%4];
}
```

Read here more about the xor_sum function:
[Find XOR of all numbers in a given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670379/find-xor-of-all-numbers-in-a-given-range?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks Ayon. Could you please explain the rationale behind `int vals[4] = {a,1,a+1,0};

    return vals[a%4];`

Comment: @user5566364, It can be explained from the pattern you will notice in the consecutive xor series (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) => (0,1,3,0,5,1,7,0..). See the link for more explanation