# Given n-1*n array, find missing number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Here each row contains a bit representation of a number.These numbers come from 1..N Exactly one number is missing.Find the bit representation of the missing number.
The interviewer asked me this question.
I said: "We can find the sum of the given numbers and subtract it from the sum of first n numbers(which we know as (N*(N+1))/2)"
He said that involves changing from base 10 to base 2.
Can you give me a hint on how I can solve it without changing bases?

Comment: Are the numbers sorted in the first place? If not, my guess would be to generate numbers from 1..N in a bit code and check if they're in the array. I found something interesting, when you divide by 2 an even binary number (such as 12(10) : 1100(2), you just have to move the digits by one to the right (12(10)/2 : 0110(2))

Comment: @Fabinout: No they are not sorted.

Comment: Your idea was actually quite great. You can easily multiply two binary numbers, then slide the digits to the right to get the sum of the numbers in the array. Then substract the sum of numbers from the array to get the final binary missing number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `XOR` together all numbers from `0`..`N` range, then `XOR` the numbers from the array. The result will be the missing number.

**Explanation:** `XOR`ing a number with itself always results in zero. The algorithm above `XOR`s each number exactly twice, except for the missing one. The missing number will be `XOR`-ed with zero exactly once, so the result is going to equal the missing number.

Note: the interviewer is wrong on needing to convert bases in order to do addition: adding binary numbers is easy and fun - in fact, computers do it all the time :-)

Comment: :Interviewer meant the step where I get the sum of first N numbers, which I would get as (N*(N+1))/2, which would be in base 10, and I will have to convert it to base 2.

Comment: @Aravind the binary multiplication is quite easy.

Comment: @Aravind Multiplying in binary is not that hard either. Anyway, unless the interviewer was looking for you to know this specific trick (which would be rather silly of him, because it borders on uselessness) he should have accepted your approach as reasonable.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the xor-sum of all numbers in the `0..N` range directly like there is to calculate the arithmetic sum using `(N*(N+1))/2`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I think there is, seen it sometime on TopCoder, but can't remember exactly.I would love to hear it.

Comment: Of course, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3932346/335858)! Are you surprised to find it on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: As it looks he was looking for this trick.Or probably there is another method, for example, he asked: Can you look at the i-th bit of the given numbers and predict the i-th bit of the missing number?

Comment: @Aravind Not without the corresponding bit of the `XOR(1..N)`. But if you have the `i`-th bit of the `XOR(1..N)`, then you can get the answer for the bit in the same way that you get the answer for the whole number.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Cool! Thanks for that link, and for the clarification.That makes sense.But go to that link you posted, look at the binary reps posted in the second top answer(based on votes), he seems to point us to a pattern, maybe we could use that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: For example, if N=5, and we have three numbers in input with last bit set to 1, then the missing number has to have last bit 0.Something of that sort.

Comment: It works quite well for me: this is a sample code:     @Test
    public final void testBitwiseXor(){
        int a = 1;
        int b=1;
        for(int i=2; i<50; i++){
            a^=i;
        }
        for(int i=2; i<25; i++){
            b^=i;
        }for(int i=26; i<50; i++){
            b^=i;
        }
        LOGGER.info(""+ (a^b));
    }

Comment: @Aravind Absolutely - you do not need to compute `XOR(1..N)` directly, you can use the special formula. Similarly, you do not need to compute `XOR` of the individual bits: counting `1`s and checking if the count is odd or even would give you the same result.

Comment: Actually, a similar trick is used in Raid parity computation/recovery. It was awesome to see it being used like this. Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight:I wish I could accept both answers, but since this answer lead to more discussion, I am accepting yours.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just XOR these numbers together, and XOR with 1..n. The fact that the numbers are stored in binary is a good hint, BTW.

In fact, any commutative operator with a inverse should work, since if the operator is commutative, the order does not matter, so it can be applied to the numbers you have and 1..n, with the difference being the first one is not operated on the number that is not in the array. Then you can use its inverse to find that number, with the two results you have. SO `+` and `-`, `*` and `/`, `XOR` and `XOR` and any other operators that meets the requirement all should work here.

Comment: Both the answers are great, but I can accept only one.I have +1-ed yours.Sorry that I couldn't accept yours.Thanks! :)

Comment: @Aravind No problem, dasblinkenlight is faster than I am - in fact, his first upvote is mine, but I believe I've edited this to be different enough so I did not delete my post. You are right that you should accept his answer:)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I can use + and - to find the missing element?Let's say for this example, 001 011 010(We are missing 4).How do we use + and - to find that?